# MyBatis @Many / Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

**I'm beginner** (sorry for my bad explanation, feel free to correct me) in MyBatis Spring-Boot, I have problem to understand and make it works @Many

I'm using 3 layer logic programming (Presentation Layer, Service Layer, Data Layer)

Thanks for your help :)

I have 3 Tables (it's TB_Products and not TB_Product as on the screenshot):

[image]

I would like to get data form table TB_Users and TB_Products to "put" it in DTO

- I create 4 java object class SearchEntity, ProductEntity (for Data layer)
- I create an interface SearchRepositoryMapper.
- I also create a SearchService interface and SearchServiceImpl as well.

Java object class:

**SearchEntity**

```
public class SearchEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9143930742617602050L;

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<ProductEntity> products;


                       // Getters and Setters code .....

}
```

**ProductEntity**

```
public class ProductEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6525703679290992635L;

    private String id;
    private String productId;
    private String product;
    private String number;
    private String date;
    private String description;


                       // Getters and Setters code .....
}
```

**SearchRepositoryMapper**

```
public interface SearchRepositoryMapper {

    // Get some fields from TB_Users and all fields from TB_Products 
    @Select("SELECT * FROM TB_Users WHERE id = #{id}")
    @Results({
            @Result(property = "id", column ="id"),
            @Result(property = "firstName", column = "firstName"),
            @Result(property = "lastName", column= "lastName"),
            @Result(property = "products", javaType = List.class, column="id",
                    many = @Many(select = "getProductIdByUserId"))})
    public SearchEntity findAllInfoByUserId(@Param("id") int id);


    @Select("SELECT *, productId FROM TB_Products WHERE productId = #{id}")
    public ArrayList<ProductEntity> getProductIdByUserId(@Param("id") int id);



    // Find id by uderId and return null if it doesn't exist
    @Select("SELECT id FROM TB_Users WHERE userId = #{userId}")
    int findIdByUserId(@Param("userId") String userId);
}
```

**SearchServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class SearchServiceImpl implements SearchService {

    @Autowired
    SearchRepositoryMapper searchRepository;

    @Override
    public SearchDto getAllInfoByUserId(String id) {

        SearchDto returnValue = new SearchDto();                                // Init returnValue as SearchDto
        int searchId = searchRepository.findIdByUserId(id);                             // Init searchId with the TB_Users id


        SearchEntity searchEntity = searchRepository.findAllInfoByUserId(searchId);

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(searchEntity, returnValue);

        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

So when I execute the code and do a GET request I get this error message:

```
{
    "message": "nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Statement returned more than one row, where no more than one was expected."
}
```

I found out that come from the mapper and `SearchEntity searchEntity = searchRepository.findAllInfoByUserId(searchId);`

But i don't know how to resolve it. The way I wrote the code is wrong

Thanks to correct me

Answer (score 1):

The exception clearly says that the query returns multiple results. Plese verify if the data in the table is correct.

Comment: Well I found out. First better to use List instead of ArrayList. Second better to use the correct import for the List which is java.util.List. And as you said use the correct type for the values....  Thanks Sereysopheak Eap ! :)